# Como utilizar mejor "se debe/se debería"

Tags: gramática

Utilizo "se debe" y "se debería" de forma cotidiana pero sigo sin entender la diferencia entre ellos.

Por ejemplo:
*Se debe realizar los siguientes cambios ...
Se debería realizar los siguientes cambios ...*

*No se debe realizar este cambio hasta ...
No se debería realizar este cambio hasta ...*

Tengo la sensación que es el equivalente de decir:
*Should/Must
Should not/Must not*

pero no estoy seguro. ¿Alguien me puede explicar?

Comment: "Se **deberían** realizar los siguientes cambios"

Comment: En estos casos, se puede usar tanto la construcción cuasi-refleja (*se deberían*) como la impersonal refleja (*se debería*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cuando dices "se debe" estás diciendo que no hay otra opción, es casi una orden. Cuando dices "se debería" estás sugiriendo algo, dejándo tu opinión a consideración sobre lo que se debe hacer. Normalmente, "se debería" es más cortés, lo puedes usar cuando no quieres imponer tu opinión sino llegar a un consenso. Si estás hablando con tus jefes o alguien "superior" normalmente debes usar "se debería", algunos podrían tomar a mal "se debe" en este contexto.
En una reunión con colegas también sería mejor visto usar "se debería". Si estás dando instrucciones a otra persona, usa "se debe"

Comment: Gracias por contestar, resulta que llevo mucho tiempo dando ordenes sin querer! A partir de ahora utilizaré "se debería" a no ser si de verdad quiero dar instrucciones/ordenes.

Answer (score 1):

Exactamente, es el equivalente de decir: Should/Must Should not/Must not. 
Cuando usas "debe" no necesariamente estás dando órdenes sólo implica que algo ha hacerce, es inmimente. En cambio "debería" es algo que "idealemente" tendría que suceder pero por varias razones no se ha hecho o no hay quien lo lleve a cabo. Así que las dos también se pueden usar en una secuencia, por ejemplo primero te das cuenta de que algo "debería" hacerse, ya que aparentemente es la mejor opción o posibilidad, luego cuando estás convencido "debe" hacerse.

Nota: en tu ejemplo dijiste "Se debe realizar los siguientes cambios ... Se debería realizar los siguientes cambios ..." la forma correcta de decirlo es "Se DEBEN realizar los siguientes cambios ... Se DEBERÍAN realizar los siguientes cambios ..."

Comment: Aunque pueda ser menos frecuente, la construcción impersonal refleja (*se debe*, *se debería*) es correcta, igual que la cuasi-refleja que propones en tu nota.